# SAML authenication in Openresty

Tags: nginx, saml, openresty

I am able to do SAML based authentication for a single URL of the application. IDP login is redirected and login is successful. But unable to generalize for all API.

But when I try to add auth_reqeust and generalize for all APIs I am getting **"auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client**" error

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:8443 default ssl; 
        ...........
        ..........
        auth_request /saml;
      

        location /saml{
                proxy_pass http://172.19.167.213:9180/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?spentityid=https://172.19.167.213/;

        }
        location /enrollment/saml/callback {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8093/saml/callback;
                return 302 https://172.19.167.213/;
        }
        
}
```

I have my IDP running on http://172.19.167.213:9180/simplesaml

Home page for protected application:- https://172.19.167.213/;

**Error details from logs:-**

```
2022/07/18 07:15:28 [error] 3511#3511: *12 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 172.19.160.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.19.167.213", referrer: "http://172.19.167.213:9180/"
2022/07/18 07:15:28 [error] 3511#3511: *12 auth request unexpected status: 302 while sending to client, client: 172.19.160.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.19.167.213", referrer: "http://172.19.167.213:9180/"
172.19.160.1 - - [18/Jul/2022:07:15:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 576 "http://172.19.167.213:9180/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [1], `auth_request` cannot handle redirects:

> If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed.
> If it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding
> error code. Any other response code returned by the subrequest is
> considered an error.

You therefore need to handle the redirects differently, perhaps [2] can help here.

Alternatively: aaybe Openresty would help with your project. It adds Lua support to nginx. There are already some community SAML implementations available [3][4]. If they don't work, you probably have to implement your own.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

[2] https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2015/03/02/sso-with-nginx-authrequest-module/

[3] https://github.com/nicoster/ngxlua-saml-sp

[4] https://github.com/hnakamur/nginx-lua-saml-service-provider